# Создать массив обьектов

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Имеется объект `item` который хранит в себе поля `name`, `password` и тд. Есть массивы: `person_name`, `person_password` в которых лежат имена и пароли. Как создать новый массив объектов `tableData` который хранит в себе объекты `item` с внесенными туда данными из массивов. Тоесть создается несколько объектов `item` и в `item.name` к примеру делается `push` из `person_name`.  Вот как я себе это представляю, но у меня не работает

```
data() {
    this.getPerson()
person_name: ['John','Mark']
person_password: ['123','321']
    let item = {
      name: '',
      password: ''
    }
    return {
this.item.name.push(person_name),
this.item.password.push(person_password),
      tableData: Array(this.person_name.length()).fill(item),
      info: null          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var item = [];
    person_name.map((v,i) => {
        item.push({
           name: v,
           password:person_password[i]
        })
    })

 в итоге

[
  {
     name: 'awdawd',
     password:4534
  },
  {
    name: 'awdaw',
    password:122321
  }
]
```

конено не плохо бы что ыб массимвы из которы берем были однинаоквый длины